# java swing timer...sigh

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to compensate for frame rate inconsistencies using the swing timer. I tried:

```
class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         timeCur = System.currentTimeMillis();
         timer.setDelay(speed - (int)(timeCur - timePrev));
         repaint();
    }
}
...
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){...
        timePrev = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
 speed=30;
 private long timePrev=System.currentTimeMillis(), 
 timeCur=System.currentTimeMillis();
```

To no avail. How to fix this?

Comment: Where did you call timer.start()?

Comment: What platform? http://mindprod.com/jgloss/time.html#ACCURACY

Comment: @vanza: I call timer.start() from a startTimer method that is called by the application logic object.

Comment: @trashgod: I ran it on ubuntu 10 and it runs absolutely terribly; I ran it on windows 7 and it runs well until I get about 600 particles on screen, then the fps takes a hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An instance of [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) fires on the event dispatch thread, coalescing events when the frame rate gets too high. You could use `setCoalesce(false)`, but I've not tried it. Also, you might compare what you're doing with this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel); although it animates fewer particles, it displays the time spent painting and allows the frame rate to be adjusted.